# assigning array index with big numers cause any issue?

Tags: php, arrays

If we define an array like `$arr[100]="sekar"` , will it create an array with 100 indexes or just 1 index  with index id of 100?

Comment: An array with a single entry in it (at key 100)

Comment: Wasn't it faster to test this yourself then making a post here and waiting for an answer?

Comment: @DainisAbols sometimes simple questions will give you headache, even  it is doesn't have the worth of giving that headache. It is that kind of question for me, really i don't know the way to test it.

Comment: @Sekar: print_r() is your friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will create an array with only one index.

Answer (score 3):

If we define an array like `$arr[100]="sekar"` , it will create an array with `1 index with index id of 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Creates array of 100 elements, initialized with "sekar" , index from 0 to 99

```
$array = array_fill(0,100,"sekar");
```

Create array of 1 element, index '100', value 'sekar'

```
$array[100] = 'sekar'; //Creates an array of size 1, index 0
```